# how to scroll a uiwebview using uiscrollview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, iphone-developer-program

i have a UIWebView over a UIScrollView. i use some js files to draw some graph like line that will update when the time value changes.

**The Problem**

Im not able to scroll when the points goes out of the screen.

I'm new to IOS Development so please help me.

thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
After Completion the QUERY, You need to close transaction.

Here's the sample code for you...

// Get the documents directory
   dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
   databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"YOURDB.db"]];

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &DB) == SQLITE_OK)

    {

        NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into studentDetails (NAME,Email,adressL1,adressL2,phone,landline,department,DoB,fatherName) values (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",
                                       name.text,
                                       email.text,
                                       addressLine1.text,
                                       addressLine2.text,
                                       phone.text,
                                       Landline.text,
                                       Department.text,
                                       DoB.text,
                                       fname.text];



            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];



            sqlite3_prepare_v2(YOURDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)

            {

                NSLog(@" Successfully added");



            } else {

                NSLog(@" Failed added");

                NSLog(@"Error %s",sqlite3_errmsg(ExplorejaipurDB));

            }

        }


        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        sqlite3_close(YOURDB);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The database could be locked because of several reasons:

- Multiple queries running
- multiple threads running
- opened the database multiple times

Check your code and see if you have closed the connections to the database **`sqlite3_close()`**. A good idea would also be to use **`sqlite3_finalize()`** after each SQL statement when you are done with it.

So try try to match all your `sqlite3_open()` with `sqlite3_close()` and `sqlite3_prepare()` (if you are using it) with `sqlite3_finalize()`